# broken npm always after install, some sort of syntax error

Tags: npm

I searched for hours now, found no same error that someone had. Every time i "repair", uninstall/install Node.js, i can see node -v, but npm -v never works in fact nothing related to npm works at all. PATH variables in Windows are all setup like they should and tried any combination that seems useful. On other machines I can use npm without problem.
There is some sort of broken software or something that always pops up:

syntax error.
syntax error.
syntax error.
"/F" cannot be processed syntactically at this point.

independent of every nodejs-version i tried. I hope someone on this planet has a solution. Using yarn is also not working.